# CrudRepository native query is giving the old value when i do select * after doing update

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to update the `RUN_STATUS` using native query as below:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "update rerun_scheduler set RUN_STATUS=:runStatus where SCHED_NAME = :scheduleName and STEP_NAME = :stepName and MODEL_ID = :modelId and SUBMITTED_TIME = :submittedTime and START_TIME = :startTime", nativeQuery = true)
int updateManualRun(@Param("scheduleName") String scheduleName, @Param("stepName") String stepName, @Param("modelId") String modelId, @Param("submittedTime") long submittedTime, @Param("startTime") long startTime, @Param("runStatus") String runStatus);
```

I am able to see the value being updated in the table using `Mysqlworkbench`. But in my code, when i try to read the status of the job as below:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from rerun_scheduler where SCHED_NAME = :scheduleName and MODEL_ID=:modelId and SUBMITTED_TIME=:submittedTime AND RUN_NUMBER = :runNumber", nativeQuery = true)
RerunDTO getJobStatus(@Param("scheduleName") String scheduleName, @Param("modelId") String modelId, @Param("submittedTime") Long submittedTime, @Param("runNumber") int runNumber);
```

Old value in `RUN_STATUS` was `"TO_DO"` when I am updating it, I am changing it to "COMPLETE". but when I am making the `Select * query`, I am still getting the `RUN_STATUS` as `"TO_DO"`. Do I have to do any save operation after the update? if so, what is the command to save?

Answer (score 0):

You may have two different transactions:

1. Some method marked with @Transactional is run. This code will call getJobStatus later.
2. After that updateManualRun is called from another thread, so another transaction is created and committed (note, that method above is still run and another transaction is still opened)
3. Since transaction for getJobStatus is still opened - it can't see updates which happened after it's start.

If it's the case - you need to call getJobStatus in separate transaction each time.

If you have service

```
@Service
class MyService {

@Autowired
JobStatusDao dao;

@Transactional
public void checkStatus() {
     Boolean  isFound=false;
     while (!isFound) {
          isFound=dao.getJobStatus() != null;
     }
}

}
```

You may want to create another service (note, that there is temptation to just create another method with @Transactional in the same service - but this won't work, check this https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying ).

```
@Service
class JobStatusService{

@Autowired
JobStatusDao dao;

@Transactional
public boolean checkStatus() {
     return dao.getJobStatus() != null;
}
```

And then you need to rewrite your original service:

```
@Service
class MyService {

@Autowired
JobStatusService service;


public void checkStatus() {
     Boolean  isFound=false;
     while (!isFound) {
          isFound=service.checkStatus();
     }
}

}
```

Btw, note that querying DB in while loop will create a decent load. 
You should add some delay between checking.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like that is the issue. But is there a way to create a new transaction every time. because, my code is running in while loop and checking for the status update. until it is in "COMPLETE" status, the loop won't exit. like you said, another transaction will be updating the status.

Comment: New transaction is opened every time when method marked with @Transactional is called (if there is no existing transaction). So, you just need to call such method. I will update my answer with example soon.

Comment: I made changes as you suggested but no luck. I am still not getting the updated value in the status.